# handlng empty batches from incoming kinesis stream in spark structured stream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

we are reading data from kinesis and outputting it to file using spark structure stream.
kinesis implementation is generating empty batches when there is no data in stream.these empty batches are creating blank files as output?
any idea how we can stop spark to write out blank files

Comment: Just check incoming record counts and if count is zero, don't call data processing function at all. Scala equivalent of this would be repartitioned.foreachRDD((rdd) => { if (rdd.count() > 0l) { rdd.foreachPartition(partitionRecords => { //do your processing here })}})

Comment: We are using stream,so data processing by spark.i want to know is there way in structure stream to write this kind of logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partitioning output fixed the empty set problem